# What is being returned by this swipe.js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

This code exists in the swipe.js library. I'm trying to customize it. The comment that precedes the return says 'exposes the Swipe API' but I'm not sure what that means.

```
function Swipe(container, options) {

...

//everything that makes the library work, including a setup() function

...


  //expose the Swipe API
  return {
    setup: function() {

      setup();

    },
    slide: function(to, speed) {

      // cancel slideshow
      stop();

      slide(to, speed);

    },
    prev: function() {

      // cancel slideshow
      stop();

      prev();

    },
    next: function() {

      // cancel slideshow
      stop();

      next();

    },...some more stuff
}
```

Is the returned value an array? Array list? Say for example I instantiate a new swipe object `window['aNewSwipeObject'] = Swipe($theDOMElement);` and I call the setup function like this `window['aNewSwipeObject'].setup()` what setup() gets called? The setup() above the return, or the setup() inside the anonymous function that is in the return of the Swipe() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning an object where each property is a reference to an anonymous function.

This is a convenient way to encapsulate/hide data. Private functions exist within the `Swipe` function (you can nest functions in JavaScript), and the individual properties for the returned object-literal are merely references to anonymous functions that call these private functions.

This way, only the `Swipe` function has access to those private, internal functions.

When you call `setup` on the object, it calls the public function (referenced by the `setup` property of the object), which in turn, calls the *internal* `setup()` function which is only available within the `Swipe` function.

Here's something that makes it cleared:

```
function myAPI(options) {

    function privateFunction1() {
       ...
    }

    function privateFunction2() {
       ...
    }

    function privateFunction3() { 
       ...
    }

    return {
        publicFunction1: privateFunction1,
        publicFunction2: function() {
            //some extra code
            privateFunction2();
        },
        publicFunction3: function() {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Now you can get individual instances by doing:

```
var myAPIObject = myAPI(options);
```

But another pattern that you will see is:

```
var myAPI = (function() {

    function privateFunction1() {
       ...
    }

    function privateFunction2() {
       ...
    }

    function privateFunction3() { 
       ...
    }

    return {
        init: function(options) {
            //do something with options
        },
        publicFunction1: privateFunction1,
        publicFunction2: function() {
            //some extra code
            privateFunction2();
        },
        publicFunction3: function() {
            ...
        }
    };
})();
```

In this instance, you will do `myAPI.init(options)` to initialize the API, but in this pattern `myAPI` is effectively a singleton (which is usually what you want, unless you want to maintain state on a per-instance basis).

Comment: By singleton do you mean there will only be one instantiation of this object? Whereas in your first example we could instantiate several objects?

Comment: @jefffabiny Yes. In the first example you can have multiple instances, but in the second example you effectively have a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

It returns an object literal. Every key in the object is a function.

This is often used to create a namespace of functions, and by placing them in the function scope, the functions will share the local scope inherited from the namespace.

For example,

```
var Namespace = (function() {
    var helperFunction = function() { ... }
    var localData = // ...

    return {
       publicFunction1 : function() { ... },
       publicFunction2 : function() { ... },
       publicFunction3 : function() { ... }
    }

})();
```

Comment: So if I call setup() on the object, is it referencing the object literal or the setup() function defined above it?

Comment: To be precise, it returns an object. An *object literal* is just a syntactic construct to create an object.

Comment: If there are two setup() functions, and one is in the `return {...}` statement and the other above it is defined as `var setup = function() {...}`, then the *latter* function is a local function, and is not exposed in the Swipe API. So you would be calling the `setup` function in the `return {...}` statement.

Comment: This is one of the advantages of placing a set of functions in the function scope. They can then have their own (shared) local scope.

Answer (score 1):

it returns the methods so the object can use them